# find the first occurrence of a word an edit the line next to it using sed command

Tags: sed, command-line

I have a file that contains the word word "string" in multiple lines. I'd like to edit/replace ONLY the whole line next to the FIRST occurrence of "string" in my file

I tried this
sed -i '/string/{n;s/.*/new-string/1}' test-file

But I am getting update on all the others lines after the others occurrences of "string"

Comment: `sed` is a poor choice of tool for doing that but you got an answer to the question you asked so if you'd like to see a better way then please ask a new question and this time tag it with `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use this:

```
sed '/string/{n;s/.*/new_string/;:a;n;ba}' input.file
```

I've added the `:a;n;ba` commands:

```
:a # defines a label 'a'
n  # read next line of input
ba # branch (jump) to label a
```

This is effectively a loop through the remaining lines until the end of the file which prints every remaining line unchanged.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that ordinarily the idiom`s/.*/replacement/` would suggest `c replacement`, however the `c` command acts in the same way `d` does and no further commands are executed for that cycle. Thus the `:a;n;ba` set of commands would never be reached and other lines in the file further on may be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'x;/./{x;b};x;/string/!b;h;n;c new_string' file
```

Use the hold space as a flag and if set, cut short any further processing.

N.B. `sed -e '/string/{n;c new_string' -e ':a;n;ba}' file` might appear to work but would introduce an error (see comment in @hek2mgl solution).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `ed` instead of `sed`:

```sh
ed -s test-file <<EOF
/string/+1c
new string
.
w
EOF
```

replaces the line immediately after the first match of the regular expression `string` with `new string` and saves the changes.